# How to avoid loosing 'this' in the callbacks?

Tags: node.js, callback, this, asynccallback

Object on which a function is called gets lost subsequently in the callbacks. How could I preserve/maintain the object on which the function was called.

```
var javaci = new Javaci();
javaci.run(actionObject.source);
javaci.once('f2run',this.output);
javaci.once('jvmo',this.output);
```

The above snippet (which is altogether in a different class)calls a `run` method of class `Javaci` and then listens for 2 events, `f2run` and `jvmo`.

But the callback function `this.output` is never called.

The following function successfully calls the subsequent `compileAndRun` function.

```
Javaci.prototype.run = function(code) {
    if(code) {
      var classDetails = this.classToInject(code);
      if(Object.keys(classDetails).length > 0) {
        code = `${classDetails['classToInject']}${code}`;
        var writer = new Writer();
        writer.write(code,`${classDetails['className']}.java`);
        writer.once('written',this.compileAndRun);
        writer.once('failed',this.failedToWrite);   
      }
    }
}
```

When the control enters the following function, `this` refers to the object of `Writer` class. How could I avoid this? Perhaps, this is the reason, the event listener function is never fired.

```
Javaci.prototype.compileAndRun = function(fileName) {
    if(fileName) {
    const child2 = execFile('javac', [fileName], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        this.emit('f2run',error);
      }else {
          var classFile = fileName.replace('.java','').trim();
          execFile('java', [classFile], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            this.emit('f2run',error);
          }else {
            this.emit('jvmo',stdout);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: `fileName => this.compileAndRun(fileName)`

Comment: @KevinB That was all! I knew of arrow functions, but thought they had to be defined inline.

Answer (score -1):

`this` usually refers to `global` in callbacks,you can try this
`writer.once('written',this.compileAndRun());`
/*******************************************/
`Javaci.prototype.compileAndRun = function () {
    var self=this;
    return function(fileName) {
    if(fileName) {
    const child2 = execFile('javac', [fileName], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        self.emit('f2run',error);
      }else {
          var classFile = fileName.replace('.java','').trim();
          execFile('java', [classFile], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            self.emit('f2run',error);
          }else {
            self.emit('jvmo',stdout);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    }
}
}`